# How to enforce different values in multiple ForeignKey fields for Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models in Django:

```
from django.db import models

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Match(models.Model):                                                      
    team_home = models.ForeignKey(Team)                                                      
    team_visitors = models.ForeignKey(Team)                                                       
    league = models.CharField(max_length=200)                                                      
    date_played = models.DateField()
```

The idea is to be able to have a 'Match' object which has two teams who played a match of some game. It would be very odd that a team be playing itself. How can I guarantee that `team_home` is not equal to `team_visitors`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This cannot be done through pure Django. There's a ticket for adding `CHECK` constraints: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11964

To ensure the situation where `team_home == team_visitors` never happens, you will need to add a custom constraint to the table which is database dependent. As an example, in MySQL and PostgresQL:

```
alter table myapp_match add constraint match_teams_not_equal check (team_home_id <> team_visitors_id);
```

This will cause the database to raise an integrity error when a save happens. Note that there are also databases where you cannot implement such a constraint.

You can partially ensure that `team_home != team_visitors` by overriding the `save` method:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    ....
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.team_home == self.team_visitors:
            raise Exception('attempted to create a match object where team_home == team_visitors')
        super(Match, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, someone can modify the database directly, or use `update` queryset in Django and you can still end up with `Match` objects where `team_home == team_visitor`.

Comment: `CHECK` constraints now have support in Django 2.2+ as part of model Meta options.

Answer (score 19):

You can use this CheckConstraint in class Meta of your django model:

```
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.CheckConstraint(
            check=~Q(team_home=F('team_visitors')),
            name='team_home_and_team_visitors_can_not_be_equal')
    ]
```

Answer (score -4):

I believe you can use the unique_together property of the Meta class: [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#unique-together)

```
class Match(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("team_home", "team_visitors")
```

Comment: Thanks! Read the documentation, seems right! Thanks alot.

Comment: This is wrong, it will **not** prevent the creation of a `Match` object where `team_home == team_visitors`. The `unique_together` constraint will ensure that for any two teams, they can only have a single match - since the combination of `team_home`, `team_visitor` must be unique.