# Django constraint for "field one not in field two for any row"?

Tags: django, django-models, django-constraints

Suppose I have a Django model with two fields one and two:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    one = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    two = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

`unique=True` means if I try to put in a row with one="one" when another such row already exists, a unique constraint will be violated.

How would I make a Django constraint that says if there is a row with one="one", then I can't put in a row with two="one"?

This does seem related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687295/how-do-i-do-a-not-equal-in-django-queryset-filtering) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64376614), but I don't quite see the answer to my question.

Comment: you can create a custom validator which will get called on the save method and there you can query the existence of that value and decide to move forward.

Comment: You can use a [constraint expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/constraints/#expressions) but your question is too vague to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

For custom validation like this I've found it best to override the save method, as @Hemal Petal mentioned:

**models.py**
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

```py
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    if MyModel.objects.filter(
        two=self.one
    ).exists():
        raise ValidationError(f'{self.one} already exists in column two!')
    
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, that's a good recommendation. Yes, I have overridden the save method. However, my question is asking if it's possible to write a constraint. The answer may be no.